# Notation to assign a statement or predicate to a symbol

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

If I want the **statement** "$4>2$" be represented by the letter $p$, how should it be written?
$$p:4>2\\
p= 4>2\\
p \equiv “4>2”$$

On the other hand, if I have two **predicates** $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, and I want to represent the conjunction of both predicates using the symbol $C(x),$ how should it be written?
$$C(x) = A(x) \wedge B(x)\\
C(x) \equiv A(x) \wedge B(x)$$

Comment: For the first, I’d say that since we’re defining ‘p’, we should say $p \overset {\mathsf d \mathsf e \mathsf f}{=} 4>2$. For the second, the best thing would be just to assume $C(x) \iff (A(x) \land B(x))$.

Comment: I would personally just write "Let $p$ be the statement $4>2$". Alternatively, you could put it in a LaTeX equation environment and it would automatically get a number. You can then use the number (with "\ref" and "\label" commands). For predicates I would indeed use notation instead of text.

Comment: @student91 which notation would you use for predicates?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali you can read the answers of the others for that. Both Pdubya and ryang have excellent suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these are unambiguous:

- Let $P$ represent the formula $4>2.$
- We use $C(x)$ to denote the formula $A(x) \wedge B(x).$
- $P\overset {\;\mathsf {def}}{\iff} 4>2$
- $C(x)\overset {\;\mathsf {def}}{\iff} A(x) \wedge B(x)$

Although `=` normally connects logic terms rather than logic formulae, these too are unambiguous:

- $P:=4>2$
- $C(x):= A(x) \wedge B(x)$

Don't write this, as it suggests that the LHS and RHS are logically equivalent by derivation instead of by definition:

> $$C(x) \equiv A(x) \wedge B(x).$$

Comment: I think $P:=2>4$ is nice, when you can do it with numbers, why shouldn't you be able to do it with booleans?  Maybe a note should be added when the notation is used for the first time...

Comment: I'm a little confused by which notation should be used for writing that the LHS and RHS are the exact same thing. Do you mean that we should use '$=$' or the double arrow with 'def' on top of it or '$\equiv$'?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali Ah, okay, does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4465471/21813) answer your question?  After reading that answer: my final sentence above means that *defining* predicate $Cx$ as $Ax∧Bx$ is a more fundamental action than discovering that the former is logically equivalent (`≡`) to the latter.

Comment: Try $p \iff  (4\gt 2)$, and $C(x)\iff (A(x) \land B(x))$ for proposition $p$ and unary predicates $A, B$ and $C$.

Comment: @ryang from that answer, if i'm understanding it correctly, i believe you're suggesting using either the symbols $\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}$ or $\:\overset{\text{def}}=\:$ for assigning a predicate to another predicate(s)?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali I don't mind either, but opinions vary.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It might be convenient to consider the usage of *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)*
\begin{align*}
[P]=
\begin{cases}
1&\qquad\text{if $P$ is true}\\
0&\qquad\text{if $P$ is false}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
We can this way define
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\mathrm{Let}\ S:=[4>2]}
\end{align*}
which has the  advantage that since $S\in\{0,1\}$ it can be used in calculations.